# Use powershell to loop through files in one folder and create txt files using those names

Tags: powershell, loops

I am looking for a script to create a text file for each file in a folder. The .txt file should use the filename of each file in that folder, but have a .txt extension instead of the original extension.

I only need to do this in a few folders so I would like to open the PowerShell window in that folder, and create the text files there (instead of having to specify the path).

I found this bit which is close, but it adds folder name and extension to the resulting .txt file

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -Recurse | ForEach {
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Temp" + $_.Name + ".txt", $_.FullName)
}
```

Comment: So, don't add folder name and extension to the resulting text file. Problem solved. Please do not post questions asking us to make trivial fixes to code you found somewhere else.

Comment: Just trying to learn by doing, Ansgar.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to filter out directories and `*.txt` files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -Recurse -File |Where-Object {$_.Extension -ne '.txt'} |ForEach-Object {
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Temp" + $_.BaseName + ".txt", $_.FullName)
}
```

I also changed `$_.Name` to `$_.BaseName` to get the filename without its extension

Comment: That is fantastic Mathias, thanks! Is there a way to filter out more files by type? To skip all media files?

Comment: Just change the `Where-Object` filter to exclude more extensions: `{$_.Extension -notin '.txt','.mkv','.avi','.mp4','.jpg','.png','.wav'}`

Comment: I see the syntax now. Is there a way to use the folder name the PowerShell window is open in instead of having to type the path name in every time?

Comment: @BadDogTitan To get the path the script is currently running from, you could use `$scriptPath = if ($PSScriptRoot) { $PSScriptRoot } else { Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process just the current folder,

1. remove the `-Recurse`
2. use `-Path '.\*'`
3. keep in mind that the command will overwrite any preexisting `.txt` files
   and also `.txt` files from other files with the same BaseName.
   To overcome this you might `Group-Object` files with the same BaseName.

I'd store this as a function in a profile, so you have always access to it.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\03\03\SO_54968726.ps1
Function New-TextRef {
  Get-ChildItem -Path '.\*' -File |
    Where-Object Extension -Notin '.txt','.mkv','.avi','.mp4','.jpg','.png','.wav'|
      Group-Object BaseName | ForEach-Object{
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(("{0}\{1}.txt" -f (Pwd).Path,$_.Name),($_.Group -join "`n"))
      }
}
```

However you name the `.ps1` script file, you can also .dot source it (load into current session).

Once active, you can simply run the function with it's name `New-TextRef` in the current folder and get your `.txt` files created.

Sample output:

```
> Get-ChildItem

    Directory: Q:\Test\2019\03\03

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2019-03-03     22:30            377 netsh_wlan_show_profiles
-a----       2019-03-04     00:31            343 SO_54968726.ps1
-a----       2019-03-03     23:02            328 SO_54972848.ps1
-a----       2019-03-03     22:32            216 SU_1410873.cmd
-a----       2019-03-03     22:47            216 test.xml
-a----       2019-03-03     23:02            194 testNew.xml


> . .\SO_54968726.ps1

> New-TextRef

> Get-ChildItem

    Directory: Q:\Test\2019\03\03

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2019-03-03     22:30            377 netsh_wlan_show_profiles
-a----       2019-03-04     00:36             43 netsh_wlan_show_profiles.txt
-a----       2019-03-04     00:31            343 SO_54968726.ps1
-a----       2019-03-04     00:36             34 SO_54968726.txt
-a----       2019-03-03     23:02            328 SO_54972848.ps1
-a----       2019-03-04     00:36             34 SO_54972848.txt
-a----       2019-03-03     22:32            216 SU_1410873.cmd
-a----       2019-03-04     00:36             33 SU_1410873.txt
-a----       2019-03-04     00:36             27 test.txt
-a----       2019-03-03     22:47            216 test.xml
-a----       2019-03-04     00:36             30 testNew.txt
-a----       2019-03-03     23:02            194 testNew.xml

> Select-String '^' *.txt

netsh_wlan_show_profiles.txt:1:Q:\Test\2019\03\03\netsh_wlan_show_profiles
SO_54968726.txt:1:Q:\Test\2019\03\03\SO_54968726.ps1
SO_54972848.txt:1:Q:\Test\2019\03\03\SO_54972848.ps1
SU_1410873.txt:1:Q:\Test\2019\03\03\SU_1410873.cmd
test.txt:1:Q:\Test\2019\03\03\test.xml
testNew.txt:1:Q:\Test\2019\03\03\testNew.xml
```

Comment: PowerShell functions are way beyond me at this point, LotPings. I tried your script removing the function references, and it did not work. I got some learning to do...

Comment: See changed script and sample session.