# Powershell scan directory of folders and files, find .docx files and create empty .txt files of the same name, in the same place

Tags: powershell, search, directory, txt

I have a directory which contains lots of folders filled with redundant .docx files. I would like to scan this entire directory including every subfolder. When a .docx file is found, I need an empty .txt file to be created with the same name and in the same location as the original .docx file. Then I will manually move the .docx files later.

So this:

```
C:\directory\file1.docx
C:\directory\subdir\file2.docx
```

Will become this:

```
C:\directory\file1.docx
C:\directory\file1.txt
C:\directory\subdir\file2.docx
C:\directory\subdir\file2.txt
```

How could I accomplish this? It doesn't necessarily have to be PowerShell either. Anything that gets the job done is fine.
Thanks much for any help!

I tried changing this script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -Recurse -File |Where-Object {$_.Extension -ne '.txt'} |ForEach-Object {
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Temp" + $_.BaseName + ".txt", $_.FullName)
}
```

Found here: [Use powershell to loop through files in one folder and create txt files using those names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968726/use-powershell-to-loop-through-files-in-one-folder-and-create-txt-files-using-th). But I couldn't figure out how to get the script to

1. Create the files in the same location as the original .docx
2. Leave the .txt files empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure no `.txt` file exists already with the same name as the `.docx` then this should work:

```
# look for any .docx file recursively
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp' -Filter *.docx -Recurse -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        $newItemSplat = @{
            Path     = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName ($_.BaseName + '.txt')
            ItemType = 'File'
        }

        # create a new item with .txt estension using
        # the directory path + the file name without extension
        New-Item @newItemSplat
    }
```

Considering there could exist a `.txt` already and you want to overwrite it, you can use `-Force` with `New-Item`.

Comment: Thank you! This is working great except for one thing. The .txt files contain the path and the file name in within them. How could I remove this so that they are empty .txt files?

Comment: @Ninjalope i didn't consider that my b. try the updated version